# ruby cron selenium-webdriver error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cron, watir

I'm trying to run ruby code with cron job and I'm using `whenever` gem.

Here is my simple code in .rb file

```
require "watir"
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.start('https://www.google.com',:firefox)
sleep 5 
browser.close
```

my crontab -l output is:

```
  PATH=/home/ba/bin:/home/ba/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

49 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which ruby >> /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/cron1.log 2>&1'

49 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which gem >> /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/cron1.log 2>&1'

49 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which rails >> /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/cron1.log 2>&1'

49 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which bundle >> /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/cron1.log 2>&1'

49 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ba/Desktop/job_1 && ruby job_2.rb >> /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/cron1.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/ba/Desktop/RoR/site_p/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-04-12 16:47:41 +0400
```

cron1.log shows this:

```
/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/gem
/usr/local/bin/bundle
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `create_response'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:97:in `create_session'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/marionette/driver.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:85:in `for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/browser.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/browser.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/browser.rb:30:in `start'
    from job_2.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]  without rvm
- Rails 5.1.6
- Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit)

  gem 'watir'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

same error comes when I try to run  cron job whith rails runner

**code runs fine from terminal.** *problem is only when i try to run it with cron job ! *

Also I try without whenever gem. Even with fresh ubuntu 16, ruby and rails.

Comment: Do you have the latest geckodriver installed?

Comment: Use Legacy Driver, don't use gecodriver.

Comment: Don't use legacy driver. Geckodriver is essentially feature complete and Selenium 4 compatible. Try running with `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` it will give you more information about what is causing that error. Also try using `webdrivers` gem, it might be an issue with having the latest driver available.

Comment: @titusfortner I am not sure whether you are practically implementing any script , geckodriver can't even be comparable to legacy driver. I am using automation and i am being paid for that in my company

Comment: @titusfortner I am practically facing many problem when I use geckodriver but not even one single problem which arises while I use geckodriver wouldn't arise when I use Legacy driver.

Comment: What issues are you having with the latest geckodriver? Most of our Watir specs are passing with it at this point. At the very least start with geckodriver first, and only investigate legacy if you are having blocking issues.

Comment: @titusfortner The above reply is for me? If you are asking please tag me otherwise I will not be notified , if you write here then OP will be notified , if you are commenting on any answer without tagging any name then the writer of the answer will be notified , so if you are talking with someone other than these two, you need to include their name.

Answer (score 1):

cron was losing **DISPLAY** environment variable while executing.

**adding ENV['DISPLAY'] = ":0" this to my script fixed my case**

details:

1. I add this  Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug  to my script (thanks a lot @titusfortner )

new log:

```
2018-04-13 09:30:01 DEBUG Selenium Executing Process ["/home/ba/.local/bin/geckodriver", "--binary=/usr/bin/firefox", "--port=4444"]
1523597401454   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1523597401458   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
1523597401713   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.cG0M1jGsI4Zn"
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
```

I saw this: **Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified**

2. because driver worked fine from shell and rails c
   i run this to find correct  value for DISPLAY
   echo $DISPLAY  or from rails c puts ENV['DISPLAY']
   result was ":0"
3. so I add this to my script and problem was solved

   ENV['DISPLAY'] = ":0"

thanks a lot for good advices
stackoverflow is super